# Create a user map with a results tables below it

Tags: 7, views, panels

I've been searching around for the past couple months, watched a lot of YouTube videos, and read a lot of tutorials, and I've made a lot of progress with an alumni directory our team is creating. But, the one challenge I haven't been able to overcome is how I might put a map of where users are located on the same page as a results table with information about them.

To give more details:

1. We are using Profile Types (Profile 2 module) to create user profiles that are similar to a LinkedIn-lite type of profile.
2. We've successfully created a nice view that is a table of searchable alumni user profiles (behind a login wall).
3. We've successfully used the Location Geo data types + Leaflet Maps + Views to create a view with a map (https://www.croomsalumni.com/user/map)
4. We've even managed to create a Panel Page that has the map and the table together (just as a test, obviously it should be laid out better).

But we haven't really found a way to make the map and the results table work together. I don't necessarily "need" the results table to be dynamic and change with the scope of the map, but it would be nice to have the filters of the table (i.e. graduation class, country, etc.) also apply to the map. But, what seems to happen instead is when one uses the filters on the table View embedded in the Panel Page the search just re-loads the page and sends it to the table View rather than sending it back to the Panel Page.

Appreciate any thoughts and different approaches.